# Removing text using regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to remove `"2011"` and everything before it plus a single space (`" "`) after `"2011"`.

Not quite sure how to approach this, all I could think of is a simple regex-like find and replace.

```
string temp;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFile1.txt");
foreach (string line in file)
{
    if (line.Contains("  "))
    {
        temp = line.Replace("  ", " ");
        sb.Append(temp + "\r\n");
        continue;
    }
    else
        sb.Append(line + "\r\n");
 }
 File.WriteAllText(@"TextFile1.txt", sb.ToString());
```

I have modified my code and with a bit of luck got it to work. Modifications look as follows:

```
if (line.Contains("2011"))
   {

   temp = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("2011 ") + 5);


   sb.Append(temp + "\r\n");

   continue;

   }
```

Comment: It is unclear what your output is supposed to look like; you specify 2011 as a search string, but your code makes no mention of this or a parameter that you can pass in to search with.  Do you simply want to eliminate extra spaces?

Comment: I've eliminated extra space, I have to eliminate some more now, every line has 2011 and some text before it, I must eliminate 2011 and everything before it in that line.

Comment: 653   09-23-2011 21 27 32 40 52 36 - is example line im working with

Comment: `string.Split()` on "2011", and throw away the first item in the split array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = "653 09-23-2011 21 27 32 40 52 36 ";
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("2011 ") + 5);
```

The result is that s = "21 27 32 40 52 36 "